# How to add spaces at certain intervals recursively in a text file (python)?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, recursion

I am learning python 3 and I like to think of myself as a beginner still.

The issue, stated as simply as I can, is I am trying to add spaces to a .txt file. It sounds easy, but it has stumped me.

So I have this huge text file of double stars and their coordinates called the Washington Double Star Catalogue. Downloading yields a text file with 30084 lines of text. I know I will consistently need to put a space 10 characters into each line and then conditionally delete a space after the next 2-4 lines.

For example

```
05597+2228STT 125      1843 2007   33   2   0   1.3   1.4  7.89  8.89 A0        -017-003 -017-003 +22 1130      055942.46+222815.0
```

The inserted space would be between the "8" and the "S." In this situation I would also need to delete the whitespace between the "T" and the "125."

I can probably handle the whitespace conditional formatting once I know how to recursively edit each line. I understand it's going to have to do with functions and a loop. I also have gotten as far as getting python to read the file.

The main reason I am trying to do this is to export it to excel, since the lack of whitespace between the WDS identifier and the discoverer code messes the import up.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although It's possible to insert spaces where you indicated, I think it's a bad strategy.  For example, empty fields are represented by spaces, so when not empty they will read in fine, but when empty they will merge with adjoining fields.  There are also other fields that can contain internal spaces beyond the ones you mention.

I think a better approach would be: break the line into individual strings based on the [WDS Bible format codes](http://ad.usno.navy.mil/wds/Webtextfiles/wdsweb_format.txt); strip the white space from the start and of these strings; replace internal spaces with underscore (_); put the data back out tab delimited.

Below is my implementation of this.  My 'Xn' codes represent empty space in the WDS format:

```
import re
import sys

FORMAT_CODES = [ \
    'A10', 'A7', 'A5', 'X1', 'I4', 'X1', 'I4', 'X1', 'I4', \
    'X1', 'I3', 'X1', 'I3', 'X1', 'F5.1', 'X1', 'F5.1', \
    'X1', 'F5.2', 'X1', 'F5.2', 'X1', 'A9', 'X1', 'I4', \
    'I4', 'X1', 'I4', 'I4', 'X1', 'A8', 'X1', 'A4', 'X1', 'A18', \
]

def format_length(fmt):
    match_object = re.match(r'[A-Z](\d+)', fmt)

    assert match_object is not None

    return int(match_object.group(1))

format_lengths = [format_length(code) for code in FORMAT_CODES]  # optimization

with open(sys.argv[1]) as catalog:
    for line in catalog:
        start = 0
        data = []

        for index, code in enumerate(FORMAT_CODES):
            stop = start + format_lengths[index]

            if not code.startswith('X'):
                string = line[start:stop]
                data.append(string.strip().replace(' ', '_'))

            start = stop

        print(*data, sep='\t')
```

On my system, this code was able to process the 30K line 00-06 hour section in about 2 seconds after manually stripping off the non-data header lines.